# libcurl with OpenSSLUnknown SSL protocol error in connection - (no Server Hello) - why?

Tags: openssl, libcurl, wireshark, ssl

I am working on an app that needs to talk to different HTTPS servers.  There are cases where server simply ignore SSL/TLS Client Hello (no Server Hello is returned).

The problem would exhibit itself in code as such:

```
>curl32.exe -v -k --tlsv1 https://...
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* About to connect() to <server> port 443 (#0)
*   Trying <IP>...
* connected
* Connected to <server> (<IP>) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ./cacert.test.pem
  CApath: none
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <Server>:443

* Closing connection #0
===> CURLcode is: 35
```

The returned code is: CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR

When running from OpenSsl directly, this would be ok:

```
OpenSSL> s_client -tls1 -connect <server>:443
```

I have tried various combination (specify TLS, SSL or not specify).  The only common thing when problem happens is when the SSL/TLS version is inconsistent.  So in WireShark I will see, under TCP, Secure Socket Layer:

- SSL Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello  <===

  - Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
  - ...
  - Handshake Protocol: Client Hello

    - ...
    - Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)

In the correct case where I will see Server Hello from server I will see:

- TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello  <===

  - Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
  - ...
  - Handshake Protocol: Client Hello

    - ...
    - Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)

I am not completely sure it is the libcurl issue, or maybe the WireShark is not decoding it correctly (as the Record Layer in both cases look almost identical, and the 2 Version fields are correct), making libcurl appears to be the problem.

Any thoughts?  Ideas?  Similar experience?  Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Typo? They look exactly the same (at least from what you have pasted).  Both are TLS 1.0 as far as the client is concerned. Wireshark defaults to printing **SSL** in the first case as the server did not send a Hello.

Comment: It _could_ be a case where --ssl-allow-beast would make a difference...

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh.  Ok so I got sidetracked by the WireShark display.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thanks for the tips!  I tried but unfortunately it does not work for me.

Comment: @MW It's far easier if you can show us the wireshark capture.

Answer (score 3):

I did more testing and debugging, and found that there are a couple of sites that consistently failed with either default or TLSv1 using Curl (curl.exe -k -v --tlsv1 , or no --tlsv1), but ok with SSLv3. I am pretty the version is not the problem, as IE connect using TLSv1 and openSSL is ok using TLSv1 also.  But I ran out of time so SSLv3 will be used as workaround.

The real problem can be the cipher list being sent out in Client Hello.  After specifying a cipher that would for sure work, SSL is ok:

```
curl.exe -k -v <site>                     # failed
curl.exe -k -v --ciphers RC4-MD5 <site>   # now will connect
```

If you have similar problem, this article has been very useful for me troubleshooting "SSL Unknown SSL protocol error" issue:

http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html